# Export existing expresso-store to new site

Tags: expressionengine, expresso-store

I've got Expresso Store set up and running on an old site. I've been developing a new site, installed a new version of Store and set up a few test-products. Any idea how to export the old products into the new site?

As far as I can see the products are stored in exp_channels and exp_store_products in the database. Can I do some export/import between the databases?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend getting something like DataGrab from AJ Weaver http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab

The data is stored in Channel Entries, so it should be as simple as exporting from the old channel and importing into the new channel.

Answer (score 2):

As Carl said DataGrab would be your best bet if you do not want to dump the entire database and import it into the new site.

Store does have some data in exp_channel_data but you would also have data in exp_store_products, exp_store_product_modifiers, exp_store_product_options, exp_store_stock, exp_store_stock_options for your products that would need to be taken care of if you were looking at doing the transfer of data manually.z